# How to limit number with 0-999 and just three numbers after the comma in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I have an input and I have to do that he can get just numbers 0-999. It should be exactly type='number' so I can not make maxLength='3' for it. max='999' also do not suitably because in this case it work not as I need. Now I have solved it with the code below (if number is bigger then 999 I divide it and leave an integer). But in this case I still can write number like 0.1234567. Maybe there is a way to do so I can write just number from 0 to 999 and if it a comma number I can write just three numbers after comma like 0.123

```
      <input
        type='number'
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => {
          let val = Number(e.target.value);
          onChange(val > 999 ? Math.trunc(val / 10) : val);
        }}
      />
```

Comment: [Use the `step` attribute?](https://jsbin.com/nicelum/1/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `toFixed()` like below.

```
     <input
        type='number'
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => {
          let val = Number(e.target.value);
          onChange((val > 999 ? Math.trunc(val / 10) : val).toFixed(3));
        }}
      />
```

Comment: toFixed work for strings but in this case it is number. And change number to string make toFixed and again change it to number is not a good solution

Comment: `toFixed()` is a number api and it'll work only on numbers. Though it returns a string. Then we need to parseFloat() if we need it in number again. Agreed, it may not be the best solution but I don't think we have any other choice to restrict a number with specific decimals.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but beside the fact that this is not related to react), standard js has attributes `min` `max`. to deny commas, you can use patterns

```
<input type="text" min="0" max="999" pattern="[0-9]+">
```